# bufio.NewReader ReadBytes - Reading multiple message at the same time

Tags: go, networking, blockchain, p2p

I have this listener function that listens on a network for messages from its peers.

It works fine must of the time but when it recieves two messages at the same time I get the following error:

" Message Decode error - extra data in buffer"

Can this be modified to allow multilpe message at the same time?

```golang
func Listen(peer Peer) {

    log.Info(" Listening for messages from: ", peer.Address)

    for {
        //will listen for message to process ending in newline (\n)
        msg, msgErr := bufio.NewReader(peer.conn).ReadBytes([]byte(`\n`)[0])
        if msgErr == io.EOF {
            peer.conn.Close()
        } else if msgErr == nil {
            msg, err := hex.DecodeString(string(msg[:len(msg)-1]))
            mgsDecoded, decodeErr := DeserializeMessage(msg[:])

            if decodeErr == nil { 
                // use decoded message here
            } else {
                log.Warn(" Message Decode error - ", decodeErr)
            }

        }
    }
}

//DeserializeMessage - Decode our message from a byte array to
//networkMessage *NetworkMessage
//over the network
func DeserializeMessage(serialized_bytes []byte) (NetworkMessage, error) {
    // Create new buffer and decoder
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(serialized_bytes)
    enc := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
    // Create new Block Instance to load the serialized block into
    var networkMessage NetworkMessage
    err := enc.Decode(&networkMessage)
    return networkMessage, err
}
```

Added how we send a message:

```
func SendMsgToPeer(networkMessage NetworkMessage, peer Peer) {

    log.Debug(" Message Sent -> Peer: ", peer.Address,
        " Command: ", string(networkMessage.Command),
        " Payload: ", string(utils.TruncateString(networkMessage.Payload, 50)))

    msg, err := networkMessage.SerializeMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("❌ Error encoding message.")
    }

    peer.conn.Write([]byte(hex.EncodeToString(msg)))
    peer.conn.Write([]byte(`\n`))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application creates and discards a buffer on every iteration of the loop. The discarded buffer can contain unprocessed data read from the connection.

Fixed by creating the the bufio.Reader once outside of the loop.

The expression `` []byte(`\n`)[0] `` evaluates to the byte `\`, not `\n`.  Fix by specifying `\n` as the delimiter.

```
br := bufio.NewReader(peer.conn)
for {
    //will listen for message to process ending in newline (\n)
    msg, msgErr := br.ReadBytes('\n')
    ...
```

The client writes the message terminator as the two bytes `\`, `n`. Change the client to write the single byte `\n` by using an interpreted [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) instead of a raw string literal.

```
peer.conn.Write([]byte("\n"))
```

If you can remove the requirement to use newline separated hex encoded messages, then you can use the gob decoder directly:

```
func Listen(peer Peer) {
    defer peer.conn.Close()
    log.Info(" Listening for messages from: ", peer.Address)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(peer.conn)
    for {
       var networkMessage NetworkMessage
       err := dec.Decode(&networkMessage)
       if err != nil {
          log.Info("decode error:", err)
          return
        }
        // do something with networkMessage
    }
}
```

Make corresponding changes to the client code. Add field `enc *gob.Encoder` to `Peer` and initialize the field to `gob.NewEncoder(peer.conn)`.  Use the encoder in SendMsgToPeer.

```
func SendMsgToPeer(networkMessage NetworkMessage, peer Peer) {
    log.Debug(" Message Sent -> Peer: ", peer.Address,
        " Command: ", string(networkMessage.Command),
        " Payload: ", string(utils.TruncateString(networkMessage.Payload, 50)))
    err := peer.enc.Encode(networkMessage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("❌ Error encoding message.")
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try putting it outside the loop I get: DecodeString->encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+006E 'n' 
  Message Decode error - EOF

Comment: with msg, msgErr := br.ReadBytes('\n') no messages are being received at all hmmm

Comment: added how we send a message